# How to restrict a user on CodeCommit from creating branches?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

I'm new to CodeCommit. I'm looking for a way to restrict users from creating branches at remote but allow him to push files to the branch.

I've created an IAM policy to deny create branch but I've allowed him to push the files to the branch.

IAM Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:CreateBranch",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesByFastForward",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesBySquash",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesByThreeWay",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:*********:MyTestReo",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": "refs/heads/myBranchName"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But the users were able to create branch using the following command.

```
git checkout -b <branchname>
git add . && git commit -m "message"
git push --set-upstream origin <branchname>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this IAM Policy:

```
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "codecommit:CreateBranch",
        "codecommit:MergeBranchesByFastForward",
        "codecommit:MergeBranchesBySquash",
        "codecommit:MergeBranchesByThreeWay",
        "codecommit:DeleteBranch"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:*********:MyTestReo"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEqualsIfExists": {
            "codecommit:References": [
                "refs/heads/myBranchName"
            ]
        },
        "Null": {
            "codecommit:References": false
        }
    }
}
```